# Extraer distintas concordancias con findall

Tags: python, string, archivo

estoy haciendo un código que me permita a partir de un string que contiene toda la información de grupos de materias, separarlos para trabajar con ellos individualmente.

(1) Grupo 1

Profesor: Fabio Alexander Suarez Bustamante.
Facultad:
Horarios/Aula: No informado
Fecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024
MIÉRCOLES de 06:00 a 08:00.
AULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.
VIERNES de 06:00 a 08:00.
AULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.
Duración: Semestral
Jornada: DIURNO
Cupos disponibles: 35

(2) Grupo 2

Profesor: Gustavo Adolfo Viana Casas.
Facultad:
Horarios/Aula: No informado
Fecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024
MIÉRCOLES de 16:00 a 18:00.
AULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.
VIERNES de 16:00 a 18:00.
AULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.
Duración: Semestral
Jornada: DIURNO
Cupos disponibles: 35

El código que hice es este:

```
import re

file = open("Udata.txt",encoding="utf8")

rfile = file.read()

grupos = re.findall("Grupo [0-9].+Cupos disponibles: [0-9]+?",rfile,re.DOTALL)

profesor = re.findall("Profesor: (.+)\.",rfile)

hora = re.findall(".+ de [0-9]+:[0-9]+ a [0-9]+:[0-9]+",rfile)

print(grupos)
```

El problema es que está extrayendo todo el string (la parte de `grupos=re.findall(...` ), o sea, haciéndolo al estilo greedy, pero no es lo que quiero, la idea es que en la lista que se genere queden separados los grupos con la información completa.

¿Hay algún comando que me estoy saltando?

Lo filtré acabando en el número de cupos que es donde en realidad terminaría el grupo en sí.

Edit: (Archivo Udata.txt)

'Logo UniversidadPORTAL DE SERVICIOS ACADÉMICOS\nInformación de la asignatura\n \t\n \nVolver\nProyecto Integrado de Ingeniería (3010439)\nTipología: DISCIPLINAR OBLIGATORIA\nCréditos:4\nINGENIERÍA ELÉCTRICA\nFacultad: FACULTAD DE MINAS\nCLASE TEORICA (3010439)\n \n(1) Grupo 1\n \nProfesor: Fabio Alexander Suarez Bustamante.\nFacultad:\nHorarios/Aula: No informado\nFecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024\nMIÉRCOLES de 06:00 a 08:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nVIERNES de 06:00 a 08:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nDuración: Semestral\nJornada: DIURNO\nCupos disponibles: 35\n \n(2) Grupo 2\n \nProfesor: Gustavo Adolfo Viana Casas.\nFacultad:\nHorarios/Aula: No informado\nFecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024\nMIÉRCOLES de 16:00 a 18:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nVIERNES de 16:00 a 18:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nDuración: Semestral\nJornada: DIURNO\nCupos disponibles: 35\n \n(3) Grupo 3\n \nProfesor: Christian Rafael Ortiz Jimenez.\nFacultad:\nHorarios/Aula: No informado\nFecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024\nMARTES de 18:00 a 20:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nJUEVES de 18:00 a 20:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nDuración: Semestral\nJornada: DIURNO\nCupos disponibles: 35\n \n(4) Grupo 4\n \nProfesor: Gustavo Adolfo Viana Casas.\nFacultad:\nHorarios/Aula: No informado\nFecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024\nMIÉRCOLES de 18:00 a 20:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nVIERNES de 18:00 a 20:00.\nAULA. M3-116. BLOQUE M3. SALON.\nDuración: Semestral\nJornada: DIURNO\nCupos disponibles: 35\n \n(5) Grupo 5\n \nProfesor: Alvaro Leon Ospina Montoya.\nFacultad:\nHorarios/Aula: No informado\nFecha:05/02/2024 - 01/06/2024\nSÁBADO de 10:00 a 14:00.\nAULA ESPECIAL. 04-207. BLOQUE 04. SALON.\nDuración: Semestral\nJornada: DIURNO\nCupos disponibles: 35\n\nPrerrequisitos\nCondición 1Tipo M¿Todas? [S]Número asignaturas []\n3010407Estructuración y evaluación de proyectos de ingeniería\nTipo de prerrequisito implica. M - no se puede matricular la asignatura sin superar el prerrequisito. O - podrá matricular, pero no ser calificado sin la superación del prerrequisito. E - o matricula el prerrequisito simultáneamente, o lo ha matriculado alguna vez. A - anulación por incompatibilidad. Si se matricula de las dos asignaturas afectadas por el prerrequisito y no supera la asignatura llave, las asignaturas afectadas por el prerrequisito aparecerán como anuladas.\nVolver\n \t \t \nUniversidad Nacional de Colombia--Dirección Nacional de Información Académica\nPortal de Servicios Académicos (V. 4.3.20) |UXXI Todos los derechos reservados'

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo se almacena en el txt que carga? ¿Cada grupo es una sola línea de texto? ¿Cómo sería el *output* esperado que deseas según el ejemplo?

Comment: @Esei, ya lo pongo, todo es un solo string, ya que lo extraje con el método read().

Comment: @Esei el output que deseo es que en la lista `grupos` queden almacenados los distintos grupos existentes con toda la info. Es para separar la información por grupo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas en la primera expresión regular.

El primero es que `.+` le estás diciendo que sea *greedy*, lo que no está mal, pero no le estás poniendo ningún alto, debe ser: `.*?` para que se detenga apenas se complete toda una coincidencia del regex (*lazy*).

El siguiente, es que el final del regex `[0-9]+?` está en modo *lazy*, por lo que solo tomará un número.

Entonces el regex corregido es:

```python
grupos = re.findall("Grupo [0-9]+.*?Cupos disponibles: [0-9]+", rfile, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: ¡Wow, entiendo! Muchas gracias. :)

Comment: aunque la instrucción `.*?` ¿por qué va en el medio y no al final del match, cómo para que lo tenga en cuenta completo?

Comment: ¿Si lo pongo solo al final es como que solo aplicara a `[0-9]+`?

Comment: @MiguelBuitrago la parte de `.*?` indica que capture todo lo que hay en medio de `Grupo xx` y `Cupos disponibles: xx` (que es lo que quieres). El signo de `?` le ordena que se detenga cuando encuentre el primer final. Si no se le pone, captura todos los grupos en un solo match, puedes hacer la prueba quitándolo.

Comment: ah ya, ¡Gracias!